# Deselect Item in Xceed grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xceed-datagrid

I have some xceed grids that I don't want any of the items to be selected by default. Right now when my grids load up, the first item is selected. Is there a way to stop this behavior from occuring?

Comment: not much hope http://xceed.com/CS/forums/thread/20851.aspx

Comment: That's brutally stupid. Thanks.